# emacs defun inserting unwanted text

Tags: emacs

I want to be able to jump to a window showing a buffer that matches a string but is not equal to an exclusion string. The jumping bit works fine but this `defun` inserts `nil` (or whatever return value the `defun` has) in the buffer it jumps to. How can I avoid this?

```
(defun myMoveToWindowNamed (name &optional exclude)
  "move to window with name that matches but is not exclude"
  (let ((wl (window-list)))
    (dolist (w wl)
      (let ((wn (buffer-name (window-buffer w))))
        (message "checking %s" wn)
        (cond  ((and exclude (string-match exclude wn)) (message "exclude"))
               ((string-match name wn)
                (select-window w)
                (return))
               (t (message "skip")))))))
```

Comment: There is no function `return` defined for Elisp's `dolist`.  Globally, `return` is an alias for `cl-return`, which likely does not do what you want here.

Comment: use `cl-dolist`, then you can have a `cl-return`

Comment: changing dolist and return into cl-dolist and cl-return does not solve the problem. the function still inserts "nil" into the buffer it jumps in ...

Comment: ... or even removing the return statement does not change the insertion of text in the target buffer.

Comment: What does work is replacing ```(select-window w)``` with ```(with-temp-buffer (select-window w))```. However, this feels a bit like overkill

Comment: Are you sure it inserts `nil`? I don't seem to get that when I run your function. You aren't using `*Messages*` as your test buffer by any chance?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect what you've done is evaluate a call to `(myMoveToWindowNamed "NAME")` by typing <kbd>C-j</kbd> in the `*scratch*` buffer.

That runs the command `eval-print-last-sexp`, and because the selected buffer is being changed, the insert from that command ends up in the new buffer.

I think your `(with-temp-buffer (select-window w))` workaround from the comments isn't so much "overkill" as it is a not-very-obvious side-effect.  The buffer selected at the end of that command loop iteration is that of the selected window; but before that happens, the current buffer for the print phase of `eval-print-last-sexp` has been restored to the buffer of the *original* selected window (in which you will observe that the return value has been inserted).

In short, if your function is called in a normal way, your problem won't occur. Just remember that <kbd>C-j</kbd> in `lisp-interaction-mode` always inserts the return value.  You can use <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>C-e</kbd> interactively to avoid that.

Comment: Thanks for that. You're right and I learned something new. Great.